# Read concatenation of json file in python

Tags: python, json

I have a text file containing multiple valid json texts, something like this

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "someID",
            "vale": "someValue"
        },
        {
            "id": "otherID",
            "vale": "otherValue"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "yetAnotherID",
            "vale": "yetAnotherValue"
        },
        {
            "id": "lastID",
            "vale": "lastValue"
        }
    ]
}
```

but with many more items per json and many more json's.

My attempt to read it *(not surprisingly)* failed:

```
import os
import json
jsonFile = open(jsonName)
jsonList=json.load(jsonFile)
```

Any sugestions to get the concatenation of all lists in a python object?

Comment: The first question is **why** you have this data. A few `,` and surrounding `[]` would transform it into valid JSON, after all. But if it really must be this way, please see the linked duplicate, particularly the answer mentioning `raw_decode`.

Comment: I take it the tool outputs the JSON as a string on the standard output, then?

Comment: Pardon; what "that" are you referring to?

Comment: **I solved the problem** by replacing the end of a json followed by the start of one with a comma: `jsonText = jsonFile.read()` `jsonList=json.loads(re.sub('\n\s*\](\n.*)+?"items":\s*\[', ',', jsonText))`